# unexpected result in function separating unique and non unique items

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop

The aim of the bellow function is to output only the non-unique items from an array that is passed as an argument:

```
"use strict";
function nonUnique(data){
    var tab = [];
    for(var d = 0; d < data.length; d++) {
        if(typeof(data[d]) == "string"){
            tab[d] = data[d].toUpperCase();
        }
        else{
            tab[d] = data[d];
        }
    }

    var count = 0;
    var tab_non_unique = [];
    var tab_unique = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < tab.length; i++){

        for(var j = 0; j < tab.length; j++){
            if(tab[i] == tab[j]){
                count ++;
            }

            if(count > 1){
                tab_non_unique.push(tab[i]);
                count = 0;
                break;
            }
            if (count == 1) {
                tab_unique.push(tab[i]);
            }

        }

    }
    return tab_non_unique;
}
```

I have tested the function by calling it on different arrays but somehow on

```
nonUnique([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
```

it fails by returning:

```
=> [ 2, 4 ]
```

I don't understand what in my code causes 2 and 4 to raise the counter higher than 1 and thus end up in the tab_non_unique array. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you reset `count` only if a non-unique is found. But it should be reset always when starting with a new number.

So put the `count=0` at the top of the loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
  count = 0;

  for (var j = 0; j < tab.length; j++) {
    if (tab[i] == tab[j]) {
      count++;
    }

    if (count > 1) {
      tab_non_unique.push(tab[i]);
      break;
    }
    if (count == 1) {
      tab_unique.push(tab[i]);
    }

  }
}
```